# Precession period matching solar year

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, precession

Consider the case of a tidally locked planet: its axis of rotation must be perpendicular to the plane of its revolution around the parent star. Therefore, no [precession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession).

**It is possible for a planets to have a precession period that is the exact same time period as the planet's solar year**, such that **the planet rotates however its seasons never change?** One pole would be in perpetual sunlight (starlight) and the other in perpetual darkness.

I am aware of the physical mechanism which causes stable tidally-locked planets, however could there be a physical mechanism which would cause a **stable precession-year ratio of 1:1**?

I am interested in the subject for the dual purpose of better understanding precession, and additionally as a plot ploy in a short story that I am authoring. Therefore answers which tend towards either or both of those goals are most appreciated.

Comment: A tidally locked planet does not require the axis of rotation to be perpendicular to the plane of revolution. It only requires the length of a day to be equal to the length of a year. The most notable example proving this point is the Moon. Its axis of rotation is not perpendicular to the plane of its orbit, which gives latitudinal lunar librations

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAFGFs1yRkI&feature=player_detailpage#t=1957 (33 minutes +). You might find the rest of the video interesting too.

Comment: @Kvothe are you implying that the moon is not tidally locked?

Comment: I'm not implying anything about the moon. That video is about a tidally locked planet, not a moon.

Comment: @Kvothe: Thank you, that is a wonderful video. I haven't seen the whole thing yet, but I will. However, interesting as it is, the video does not address the question of a stable 1:1 precession:year ratio.